# Change List Tile trailing using provider

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-provider

The problem is that when a List Tile is tapped the quantity is incremented for all the list tiles.

I have a stateless widget which has this build method :

```
final ProductsList productsList = ProductsList(context);
return Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: productWidget(productsList, args)));
  }
```

This is the ProductWidget

```
  FutureBuilder productWidget(productsList) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getProducts,
      builder: (context, products) {
        switch (products.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Text('Loading....');
          default:
            return Scaffold(
                body: productsList.build(products.data));
        }
      },
    );
```

And this is what productsList.build does:

```
  ProductsList(this.context);

  Padding getProduct(name) {
    int _quantity = Provider.of<Quantity>(context).getQuantity();
    return ListTile(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        onTap: () {
          Provider.of<Quantity>(context, listen: false).incrementQuantity();
        },
        title: Text(name),
        trailing: Text("$_quantity"),
      ),
    );
  }

  ListView build(products) {
    List<Widget> _products = new List();

    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
      _products.add(getProduct(products[i].name));
    }

    return ListView(
      children: _products,
    );
  }
```

and I am using this changeNotifier :

```
class Quantity extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _quantity = 0;

  void incrementQuantity(){
    _quantity += 1;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int getQuantity() {
    return _quantity;
  }
}
```

I want to tap a list tile and increment just it's value which is displayed in the trailing, but not of the others.

I am using multi-provider in the main file of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Provider needs to track quantity by product.  Your Provider is tracking quantity as a single int so the result you are seeing is correct for your code.

Quantity should be List.  You can also set the initial value.

Then

```
incrementQuantity(int index) {
 increment quantity[index] here
}
```

And

```
get quantity(int index){
 return quantity[index]
}
```

On a side note, in my opinion, your efforts would benifit greatly by researching using ListTile with Provider.

Comment: I am not sure how I can bind each tile to a quantity. How can I provide a list of bindings in the ListView?